# maven build execute svn get

Tags: maven-2, version-control, maven-plugin, maven-scm

I have a project build that needs to include files from another svn location during the build. I want to execute an svn get and then copy these files to the appropriate folder for the build. Researching this issue it seems I could use ant tasks but I wanted to find out what might be the best approach to take for this build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [maven-scm-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/index.html). According to the [scm matrix](http://maven.apache.org/scm/matrix.html) both checkout and update are allowed.

Comment: I was able to use the maven-scm-plugin to solve this issue. Instead of a get I ended up having to use a checkout to the folder I wanted these files to live to be safe I then update it although I am pretty sure this is redundant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Robert's answer is good, if the project is large though you'll be checking out a lot of content to get e single file.

If you want to get an individual file from SCM, the [Maven SCM API](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-api/index.html) allows you to interact directly with an SCM repository to invoke arbitrary goals. In this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130365/maven-commit-single-artifact-to-svn-repository/1131279#1131279) I provide an example of a custom Mojo that commits a single file, if you implement that mojo and change the command from *add* to *checkout* you'll avoid having to checkout the entire project.